Is it possible to find $\left(f^{-1}\right)^{[n]} (f(x))$ using only $f$ and its derivatives, assuming $f$ is one to one?
I'm trying to find higher derivatives for $f^{-1}$ at a defined point $(x,f(x))$. I know that $\left(f^{-1}\right)'(f(x)) = \frac{1}{f'(x)}$, but my calculus is nowhere near what it used to be, so I haven't made any progress moving on past that. I can use $f$, $f'$, $f''$, etc, since I can easily find what those are.

Related question. There is also a recurrence relation for the next coefficient in terms of a finite sum of the previous ones, but it cannot be found.

So, the derivative for $f^{-1}$ is derived by using the fact that
$$
f^{-1}(f(x)) = x
$$
and then differentiating both sides according to the chain rule. We would get
$$\newcommand{\f}{f^{-1}}
\newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
\newcommand{\dv}[1]{\frac{\dd #1}{\dd x}}
(\f)'(f(x)) \cdot f'(x) = 1
$$
The $n$th order derivative presumably can be derived from here via Faà di Bruno's formula,
$$
\frac{\dd^n}{\dd x^n} f(g(x)) = \sum_{\substack{m_1,\cdots,m_n \in \mathbb{Z}_{\ge 0} \\ 1m_1 + 2m_2 + \cdots + nm_n = n}} \binom{n}{m_1,\cdots,m_n} f^{(m_1+\ldots+m_n)}( g(x)) \prod_{j=1}^n \left( \frac{g^{(j)}(x)}{j!} \right)^{m_j} 
$$
and the general Leibniz (product) rule,
$$
(f \cdot g)^{[n]}(x) =\sum_{k=0}^n {n \choose k} f^{[n-k]}(x) g^{[k]}(x)
$$

Can you elaborate please?
